# Как установить angular cli на компютер без интернета?

Tags: angular4, angular5, angular, install

Не могу установить angular cli на компютер с работы, он выдает ошибку 443 порта, но дело в том что порт открыт но по соображениям безопасности проверяется антивирусом и по этому npm выдает ошибку, как установить локально из папки с github, angular cli и другие фреймворки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте на прямую с гитхаб установить, так тоже работает

```
npm install -g <git repo url>
```